# Tourism after business trip

Tags: visas, schengen

I will be going to Finland for a week on business trip. After this I would like to go as a tourist to Switzerland and Prague for a week. What visa do I apply for?

The Finland embassy also told me that Switzerland is not a part of the Schengen area.

Do we have a official website where we can see the list of countries?

Comment: The [list](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/schengen_visa_en) can be found on the EU's website and Switzerland is clearly a member.  The Finnish embassy is wrong, or else you have some sort of miscommunication.

Answer (score 1):

Switzerland **is** a member of the Schengen area, and has been for several years now.

You should apply for a visa for the country where the ["main purpose" of your trip occurs](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf), in this case that would presumably be Finland:

> You must lodge the application for a Schengen visa at the Consulate of
>   the country that you  intend  to  visit,  or –if  you  intend  to 
>   visit  more  than  one  Schengen  State,  the Consulate  of  the 
>   country of  your  primary  destination  (i.e.  main  purpose  of  stay
>   or longest stay).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-countries-list/
You can apply for visa at the Finnish embassy. You can travel with that visa to Prague and Switzerland.

Comment: Please don't link to schengenvisainfo.com -- it is a private website that exists to sell ads and is infamous for giving misleading or out-of-date information.